# Angular Data table not being filled with response object from API

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to fill my data Table using an API call to get my data. However it doesn't seem to wanna fill my table even though in a console.log it show the response like so:
[image: console log result]

Here is the code that I use to try and fill my table:

```
this.beheerService.getAccessPoints().subscribe((result => {
  if (!result) {
    return;
  }

  console.log(result);
  this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(result);
}))
```

And as requested the template code:

```html
<div id="tableContainer">
  <h1 class="mat-h1">
    <fa-icon [icon]="faTicketAlt"></fa-icon> Xirrus Accesspoints
  </h1>
  <div class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
      <!-- ID Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> ID </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.id}} </td>
      </ng-container>
      <!-- Name Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.name}} </td>
      </ng-container>
      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>
    <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]" aria-label="Select page of users"></mat-paginator>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can't figure out where its going wrong I hope someone could shed some light and help me out.

Comment: What is supposed to be passed as a parameter into the ```new MatTableDataSource(``` call? Is it the ```response``` array with 1065 entries?

Comment: Looks like you want `this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(result.response);`

Comment: @OvidijusParsiunas Yes `response` is supposed to be used as the source.

Comment: What does `console.log(this.dataSource)`  from outside the subscription print?

Comment: Have you got displayedColumns = ['id', 'name']; etc. in your .ts file?

Comment: @tony That returns me a `MatTableDataSource` but the `data` is empty.

Comment: @MattSaunders Yes I have both in the .ts file.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to set your data source as follows:

```
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
```

and then in your subscription function

```
this.dataSource.data = response;
```

Can you also confirm you have `[dataSource]="dataSource"` in the table tag in your template - see [this basic example](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview)? I'd recommend adding your template code to your question.

Comment: I've added the template code in the question. Unfortunately your suggestion didn't work.

Comment: As per the Stackblitz in my answer, you should be able to get the table working without using MatTableDataSource just using the array of results. I'd forget about MatTableDataSource for now and focus on getting the table displaying with an array. Then revisit MatTableDataSource if it's really needed

Comment: Check this link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dvrbmv?file=src/app/table-basic-example.ts

MatTableDataSource is not needed. (Sorry - fixed link)

Answer (score 0):

Ts :

```
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

   dataSource: MatTableDataSource = new MatTableDataSource([]);
   isDataSourceLoaded = false;

   constructor(
    private dataService: DataService
   ) { }

   ngOnInit(): void {

    this.getData();
   }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {

      if (this.isDataSourceLoaded === false) {
        this.getData();

        if (this.dataSource.data.length !== 0) {
          this.isDataSourceLoaded = true;
        } else {
          this.isDataSourceLoaded = false;
        }
      }


  }


  getData(): void {

    this.dataService.getData().subscribe((result => {
       if (!result) {
         return;
       }

       this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(result);
    }));

    if (this.dataSource.data.length === 0) {
      this.isDataSourceLoaded = false;
    }

  }

}
```

Html :

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  ...
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

My wild guess is that you are using `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`.

this means that your component will detect changes only when `@input` values are altered (you may not even have them)

You receive data but it cannot be detected outside subscription because you probably dont force change detection.

Try importing
`import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';`

insert it in costructor
`constructor (private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {}`

and force change detection like below

```
this.beheerService.getAccessPoints().subscribe((result => {
  if (!result) {
    return;
  }

  this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(result);
  this.ref.detectChanges(); <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
}))
console.log(this.dataSource); // log dataSource from outside the subscription and see if it has data
```

Also, can't you just subscribe to result from template using async pipe?

This would prevent all the above written stuff